# How to have the same \parencite citation format in the paragraph and in the figure caption?

Tags: biblatex, overleaf, bibliographystyle

I have used the below-mentioned code for citing the bibliography in my master's thesis.

```
\usepackage[sorting=none, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}
 {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
 {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{[\usebibmacro{cite}]}}
   %                        ^                  ^
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

To be specific:

```
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
     \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{images/lariman's_scan.png}
     \caption{Scanning strategies: (a)-alternate hatches, single pass of laser beam; 
     (b)- alternate hatches, multiple passes of laser beam; (c)- cross hatches, 
    single pass of laser beam.\parencite{LARIMIAN2020138455}}
    \label{fig:6}
    \end{figure}

   \noindent C. Elangeswaran et al.\parencite{ELANGESWARAN2020108962} assessed the 
    influence of \textbf{microstructure} on the fatigue behavior of 316L stainless 
    steel manufactured by laser powder bed fusion. They considered four different 
    material conditions: as-built, stress relieved, fully annealed, and hot isostatic 
     pressed (HIPed). From the fully reversed tension-compression fatigue results 
     they reported that as-built and stress relieved specimens exhibited superior 
     fatigue resistance compared to the other two material conditions. \par
```

But citations in the paragraph are fine but in the figure caption, the whole title of the cited papers is shown.
[image]

Is there any way to have the same format of citations in the paragraph and also in the figure caption?

Also is there any way to hyperref only the cited text between the square brackets e.g. [Elangeshwaran et al. 2020]. I would like to hyperref only Elangeshwaran et al. 2020 excluding square brackets.

For the 2nd part of my question, a simple compilable code:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}



\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=28mm, top=1cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[rflt]{floatflt}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2212}{-}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[sorting=none, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{hadamard.bib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{[\usebibmacro{cite}]}}
  %                        ^                  ^
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\vspace{-10em}
\title{\textbf{Jacques Hadamard}}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\vspace{-5em}
\begin{abstract}
Jacques Salomon Hadamard (né le 8 décembre 1865 à Versailles, mort le 17 octobre
1963 à Paris) est un mathématicien français, connu pour ses travaux en théorie des nombres,
en analyse complexe, en analyse fonctionnelle, en géométrie diﬀérentielle et en théorie des
équations aux dérivées partielles.


\end{abstract}

{
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
  \tableofcontents
}

\section{Biographie}

\subsection{Famille et années de formation}


\subsection{Carrière d'universitaire}


 \section{Postérité scientiﬁque}
 
 \section{ Les matrices de Hadamard}
 Une matrice de Hadamard est une matrice carrée dont les coeﬃcients sont tous 
1 ou –1 et dont les lignes sont toutes orthogonales entre elles. Le nom retenu
 pour ces matrices rend hommage à Jacques Hadamard, même si les premiers 
 exemples systématiques sont dus à James Joseph Sylvester. \parencite{Ponche}\par
 \vspace{3em}
 
 \noindent{\Large{\textbf{Examples:}}}\par
 \vspace{0.7em}
 \begin{center}
 $H_1 = (1), \ H_2 = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1\\
1& -1
\end{pmatrix}, \ H_4 =  \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
  \end{center}
\noindent{\Large{\textbf{Ordres possibles :}}}
 \begin{itemize}
     \item [--] L'ordre d'une matrice de Hadamard est nécessairement 1, 2 ou un multiple de 4.
     \item [--]  \textit{Construction de Sylvester} : si H est une matrice de Hadamard, alors la matrice $\mathbf{H \otimes H_1 =  \begin{pmatrix}
   H & H\\
H& -H
\end{pmatrix}}$
 est une matrice de Hadamard d'ordre 2n\\
On en déduit par récurrence l'existence de matrices de Hadamard d'ordre 2$^n$
\item [--]  \textit{Théorème de Paley} :
Pour tout entier $n > 0$ multiple de 4, si $n−1$ ou $n/2−1$ est une puissance d'un nombre
premier, alors il existe une matrice de Hadamard d'ordre n.
\item [--] \textit{Conjecture de Hadamard} :
Pour tout entier n > 0 multiple de 4, il existe une matrice de Hadamard d'ordre n.
 \end{itemize} 
 
\section{Sources and References} 
\indent1. Article \href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Hadamard}{Jacques Hadamard} from wikipedia.\\
\indent2. Article \href{https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrice_de_Hadamard}{Matrice de Hadamard} from wikipedia.


\nocite{Mandelbrojt}
\nocite{Mazya_1}
\nocite{Mazya_2}

%\bibliographystyle{apalike}


\printbibliography

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From the above figure, I want to hyperref only PONCHE et al. 2012, excluding the square brackets. Is there any way?

Comment: For the second issue you can use `\textcite` instead of `\parencite` and leave out the manual mention of the author. For the rest of the question it would help if you can provide more information. What is the contents of the `.bib` file for these two entries? What is the documentclass and other packages used? Ideally you should provide a full document that can be compiled without errors from the provided code that shows the current behavior. Also: why do you declare the `\parencite` command manually (given that it is built-in into `biblatex`)?

Comment: We definitely need to see the relevant `.bib` entries for the two citations. Ideally you would also turn the code snippet into a compilable example document (and run that to verify that is indeed reproduces the issue). In the `authoryear` style `biblatex` will use the title to replace missing authors/editors. So maybe you did not supply a (valid) `author` for `LARIMIAN2020138455`.

Comment: @moewe I checked the .bib file and yes the author name was missing for this LARIMIAN2020138455 citation.

Comment: Does that mean that your problem is resolved or is there anything else going on? (It's hard to say without compilable code.)

Comment: @moewe For the first part of my question, yes it's resolved. But for the second part of my question; I'm enclosing the simple compilable code.